Center Bootstrap 5 columns and stack them in a grid pattern
I have a Bootstrap 5 row with the justify-content-center utility to keep the columns centered relative to the web page. This ensures equal space on the left and right sides of the container regardless of the page size.
Here is a piece of my HTML:


.state-online {
  color: #00adef;
}
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-4 row justify-content-center m-0" id="row">
      <div class="col p-0" id="col" style="order: 0;">
        <div class="table-responsive card m-0 ms-1 me-1 mt-2">
          <table class="table table-borderless align-middle m-0" id="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-start" id="title">Name 1</td>
                <td class="text-end text-nowrap" id="state">
                  <svg class="state-online align-text-top" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                    <path d="M256 512A256 256 0 1 0 256 0a256 256 0 1 0 0 512z"></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span>online</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="icon">
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png" style="height: 150px;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="text-center" id="button">
                  <a class="btn btn-primary w-100">Connect</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot class="table-group-divider" style="display: none;"></tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- col -->
      <!-- col -->
      <!-- col -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



Is it possible to stack columns in a grid pattern as shown in the picture, maintaining the same responsive behavior and keeping the margins between the columns fixed-sized?

One important thing to note is that I want to stack columns like this only if I have more than one line of elements (in my case, 4 col elements per line). So, using justify-content-start is not an option for me.
Here is an example of how it should look like with only one line (2 columns):

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Not exactly sure of what the issue is. You have a container that is already adding margin on the sides of the page, thus the whitespace shown above it is maintained. Now you want the cards to be displayed in the center of the screen or starting from the right? The black arrow on the first screenshot indicates that. Why justify-content-center wouldn't be an option? Asking in an attempt to understand fully the issue

So, is your intention to have the grid centered with the last cell being aligned to the left, and when the grid has 3 or less cells, it will be centered? Please clarify.

@OptimalCoder yes, that's exactly what I want. I would like the last row to be left-aligned if it contains less than four cells. Ideally, this should work for any number of cells per row, as I may change the row length to 3 or 5 cells.

@Petros the black box and arrow indicate where I want the last cell to be placed. If the last line contains 2 or 3 cells, I would also like them to be left-aligned. I'm currently using justify-content-center, but it doesn't achieve the desired alignment.
